# SceneKit rotate node twice only performs last rotation?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am trying to tell a node to rotate like this:

```
    node.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, -Float(M_PI))
    node.rotation.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, -Float(M_PI_2 / 2.9))
```

I don't understand why the only rotation that works is the last one. It looks like the first rotation does not do anything.

How can I rotate a node by a certain angle on the Y axis and then another angle on the x axis? What am I missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding to the rotation, you are assigning a new value replacing the previous value.

I think the property that would suit you better is `eulerAngles`. It's the orientation expressed as [roll, yaw, and pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait.E2.80.93Bryan_angles) angles. Note that assigning a new vector still replaces the previous value. Also note that the order is roll, yaw, and pitch despite the components of the vector being called x, y, z. This means that `node.eulerAngles.x` changes the node's rotation about its **z**-axis.

Comment: makes sense. I will try this out and report back.

Comment: Sorry it took long to mark it as correct. I wanted to test it in project that took me longer than I thought. Thanks!